# Labelled in-line equation

Tags: equations, inline

I searched the internet but I cant find a solution for my problem. I want a numbered and labelled equation inside the text.Something like:

```
The equation a+1=b (2.1) does ...
```

The equation a+1=b shouldn't be in a new line like usual

```
The equation
a+1=b (2.2)
does...
```

Comment: Hi Paul, [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) I edited the title of your question- hope it's ok :) If not, please feel free to role it back. Welcome to the group!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The following defines `\inlineequation`:

```
\inlineequation[<label name>]{<equation>}
```

- Optionally `<label name>` can be given for referencing the equation.
- `\label` afterwards keeps the previous referencing behavior like
  an environment `equation` would have done.
- `\refstepcounter` is called at the beginning of the inline equation, because
  package `hyperref` sets the anchor here.
- A numbered equation should probably not be broken across lines. This is
  prevented by the penalty settings at the beginning without loosing stretchability of glues. With `\hbox` or `\mbox` the strechability would be lost.
- The equation number is set by `\@eqnnum` that takes care of the formatting of the equation number as in environment `equation`. It is responsible for adding parentheses
  and font settings.

The example file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\inlineequation}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    % Put \refstepcounter at the beginning, because
    % package `hyperref' sets the anchor here.
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      \label{#1}%
    \fi
    % prevent line breaks inside equation
    \relpenalty=10000 %
    \binoppenalty=10000 %
    \ensuremath{%
      % \displaystyle % larger fractions, ...
      #2%
    }%
    ~\@eqnnum
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
The equation        
\inlineequation[eq:inline]{a+1=b}
does \dots
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 21):

I'm not sure if this is a good idea or not (imagine a new reader searching for equation 2.1, for example), but the following seems to do what you want; note that I've used `refstepcounter` to increment the `equation` counter.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
The equation $a+1=b~\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)\label{myeq}$

Here is a reference: \eqref{myeq}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Not a good idea, also in my opinion, for the same reason you mention.

Comment: used it to number an inline equation in an itemize environment; looked awesome, works perfectly, even with hyperref, thumbs up!