# How to get align environment in the same line as text

Tags: environments, align

I would like to have an align environment which is not automatically written in a new line.
For example in the following code, the formulas should appear in the same line as the itemize-dot or the *Proof.* :

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
    \item
    \begin{align*}
    x & = 0 \\
    y & = 15
    \end{align*}
\end{itemize}

\begin{proof}
    \begin{align*}
    x & = 0 \\
    y & = 15
    \end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

I know that I could use `$\displaystyle x=0$` for single lines but the align environment is clearly better when aligning more than one line of formulas. Does anybody have an idea?

Comment: You can take a look at [these answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/281523/using-equation-inside-description/281527#281527) to a recent similar question or to [these](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate)

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This question is very similar to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/9394/vertical-alignment-of-align-in-enumerate. Please take a look at it as the information there might help you. If so, that's great, and we'll probably close this question as a duplicate just to keep the place tidy and to help people find answers quickly. If not, please edit your question here to explain why so that people can better focus their attention to help you.

Comment: @cryingshadow ^^ I think the comment was intended for you, although hard to be sure.