# Can we write an equation in a single line with text and equation number?

Tags: equations, numbering

I am writing an equation using the following

```
\begin{eqnarray}
\max\{|P_4|\} = \frac{m+2}{2}
\end{eqnarray}
```

which gives me output in the following way:

[image]

Can I insert the equation with equation number just after text? Is it possible to do so? It is taking too much space on a page and I have to write at least six such equations. Kindly help.

Comment: (1) never use `eqnarray`, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197/3929, (2) it will probably be very bad for the reader if the (1) is hidden as a part of the text, they will see it as a reference to an equation number they cannot find.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether this is what you had in mind, I can delete this post otherwise.

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78579/labelled-in-line-equation
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\inlineequation}[2][]{%
  \begingroup
    % Put \refstepcounter at the beginning, because
    % package `hyperref' sets the anchor here.
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    \ifx\\#1\\%
    \else
      \label{#1}%
    \fi
    % prevent line breaks inside equation
    \relpenalty=10000 %
    \binoppenalty=10000 %
    \ensuremath{%
      % \displaystyle % larger fractions, ...
      #2%
    }%
    ~\@eqnnum
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

A shortest $u_0-u_i$ path is $P_1:u_0,v_0,v_3,v_6,\cdots,v_i,u_i$ containing $i/3$ 
edges from $C_1$ and two edges from $M$. Length of $P_1$ is $(i+6)/2$ and maximum
of $P_1$ is for $i=3m/2$, i.e., \inlineequation[eq:inline]{\max\{|P_4|\} = (m+2)/2}\\

Now a reference to Eq.~(\ref{eq:inline}), which states that 
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Up to some extent this solved my problem. Thanks a lot. Really helpful