# How can I Show label of equations only in one chapter of my thesis

Tags: chapters

For some equations I need to visible their label, for example:

```
/begin{equation}    
    /label{eq:C3}    
    x+y=3    
/end{equation}
```

I also used the package `showlables`.

In this case for each equation I received one number and one label

this happens for all equations from the first page to the last page like that:

```
$x+y=3 $       $ (1.1) (eq:C3)$
```

But I need the label `$(eq:C3)$` just for the equations which are in my last chapter.

Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: presumably you used `\begin` not `/begin` `showlabels` is just for debugging so why does it matter if it applies to the whole document?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle the package which I used before /begin{document} is /usepakage{showlables}, So what do you mean by /begin{showlables} ?

Comment: @Angela Might this be useful https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78579/labelled-in-line-equation. David was referring to your past `MWE` where you used `/` instead of `\\` (for some reasons, I am not able to highlight my \).

Comment: sorry my comment was two separate comments, the first is asking why you are using `/` not `\ ` everywhere?  you have posted fragments like `/begin{equation}` which means no one can use your code.  the second comment was asking why you only want to use `showlabels` for part of the document, it is just a debugging package and should not affect the final document at all, so why does it matter if the debugging strings appear in all of the chapters?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle so sorry for this mistake "/"! I use my phone for writing questions in original documents that's"/begin".

Comment: Someone had fixed your example and you have just made them all / again, please revert that edit. The label is just an internal cross referencing string and it should _never_ appear in the final document, also do not use labels that are related to the equation number such as `eq:C3`

Comment: the image that you post to seems completely unrelated to teh question, did you intend to post a different image?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I didn't post this image. I don't know how it came here, !!!!

Comment: The question is very confusing in its current state. Can you explain your problem in more detail?

Comment: @Johannes_B I just want to visible equations label for one chapter of my thesis, I have a lots of equations and when I used package showlables for all equations I have a number and also a label and it makes my work ugly! the problem is that for some equations I just need number of equations for another I want to show label without number and for some both. In latex is this possible????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to be able to turn on and off the printing of the labels by the `showlabels` package. The code below shows how you can define two macros `\ShowLabels` and `\HideLabels` that will do just that.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showlabels}
\let\OriginalLabelFormat\showlabelsetlabel
\newcommand\ShowLabels{\let\showlabelsetlabel\OriginalLabelFormat}
\newcommand\HideLabels{\renewcommand\showlabelsetlabel[1]{}}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
a=a  \label{a}
\end{equation}

\HideLabels % turns off showing of labels for the following equations
\begin{equation}
a=b  \label{b}
\end{equation}

\ShowLabels % turn on labels again
\begin{equation}
a=c  \label{c}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```