# Keep inlineequation counter fixed during overlays

Tags: align

In this page [Labelled in-line equation](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78579/labelled-in-line-equation), a labelled in-line equation was defined. I want to know how to fix its counter if it appeared inside other math environments like align for example. Here is a sample code:

```
\begin{align}
z+2 = 5\only<1>{\nonumber}\onslide<2->{\Rightarrow z = 3,}\\
\inlineequation[eq:inline1]{x^2 + y^2 = 1.} \onslide<3>{\Rightarrow \text{bla bla bla}.}\only<1,2>{\nonumber}
\end{align}
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want to fix the counter of inlineequation at (1).

Comment: It is very unclear to me what you want to achieve. Why do you want to put an inline equation inside an `align` environment in the first place? Isn't the idea of having an inline equation to exactly not put it inside such environments?

Comment: Dear @Jasper Habicht, I use overlays in my presentations. The inline equation itself implies several results. It is also used as a reference several times in the presentation; hence, must be cited several times. Therefore, I prefer to give it a fixed label that doesn't change over successive overalys. Hope this answers your question.