# How can I fit equations with numbering into a table?

Tags: tables, equations

I would like to put multiple equations in a table like below.

| solved for x | solved for y |
| --- | --- |
| x = a + b (1.1) | y = d + e (1.2) |
| x = d + b * k (1.3) | y= j^2 (1.4) |

the equation should be aligned to the left and the numbering to the right. I've not been able to fit the equation envrioment into a table so the equations will be numbered.

Comment: Welcome! Is it possible that this question is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78579/labelled-in-line-equation  (with [Heiko's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78582/38080) )?

Comment: Not really. If i use the inline equation, the numeration is not oriented to the right of the cell and if I have a fraction it is made smaller in the inlineequation compared to the equation envrioment.

Comment: @Olerf If you are using columns with defined width, the alignment can easily be done using `\hfill`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update**
As pointed out in the comments, the first version did not add an option to refer to equations. Hence, `\addtag` was redesigned and moved directly inside the cells making numbering optional. Additionally, an argument of `\addtag[<label>]` is optional. It is a label name and is required only if the equation needs to be referenced.

[image]

The new code

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newcommand\addtag[1][]{%
  \refstepcounter{equation}\hfill(\theequation)%
  \notblank{#1}{\label{#1}}{}}
\counterwithin[\arabic]{equation}{section}


\begin{document}
\section{First section}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \centering
  \caption{Equations}\label{tab:equations}
  \begin{tabular}{| *2{>{\(}p{5cm}<{\)}|}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Solved for $x$} & \textbf{Solved for $y$} \\
    \hline
    x = a + b          \addtag[a] & y = d + e \addtag[b] \\ 
    x = d + b \times k            & y = j^2   \addtag[c] \\ 
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

References: Euqation~\ref{a}, Equation~\ref{b}, and Equation~\ref{c}.
\end{document}
```

EDIT.
Note the equation numbers. The document class `article` defines equations as single numbers, whereas `report` and `book` will add a chapter to form a combined tag, that is `(2.1)` etc. as long as `\chapter` is used. If you wish to have the same effect using just `article`, add the following code to preamble:

```
 \counterwithin[\arabic]{equation}{section}
```

EDIT2. (display style)
Inline equations by default are typeset using a text style, which is a more compact form to fit expressions between texts. This can be changed by appending `\displaystyle` to each expression. However, `>{...}` can do that automatically per each cell in the column. See the snippet below. You just need to add `\displaystyle` after `\(`

```latex
  \begin{tabular}{| *2{>{\(\displaystyle}p{5cm}<{\)}|}}
    % ...
  \end{tabular}
```

Equations may no longer fit the rows after the change. In that case, increase the stretching factor of `\arraystretch` to something larger than 1.8, e.g.

```
\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.85}
```

---

Here's a simple solution

[image]

```latex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\newcommand\addtag{\;\refstepcounter{equation}(\theequation)}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[tbh]
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.5}
  \centering
  \caption{Equations}\label{tab:equations}
  \begin{tabular}{| *2{>{\(}p{5cm}<{\hfill\addtag\)}|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textbf{Solved for $x$}}
    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\textbf{Solved for $y$}} \\
    \hline
    x = a + b          & y = d + e \\
    x = d + b \times k & y = j^2 \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding the tag via `<{…}` code is a nice idea, but it makes it difficult to set labels to the equations if needed.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I've addressed the issue.

Comment: @Celdor I've used your version, thanks! the only thing i have a problem with are fracs inside the table. They are displayed way smaller than inside the equation envrioment. Is there any easy fix to that problem?

Comment: @Olerf That's an easy change. See _Edit2_ in my answer. In general, inline equations, in texts, are rendered using `\textstyle` as they would take too much space, otherwise. If you add `\displaystyle` in front of an expression, you tell LaTeX to use the regular format.

Answer (score 5):

As @Rmano already suggested in a comment, this can be done using [Heiko's answer here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78582/38080). To do the right alignment in a column, you just have to use columns with defined width and `\hfill` instead of just a non-breakable space `~`. Here a suggestion with a slightly improved code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\InlineEquation}{om}{%
  \begingroup
    % Put \refstepcounter at the beginning, because
    % package `hyperref' sets the anchor here.
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    % prevent line breaks inside equation
    \relpenalty=10000 %
    \binoppenalty=10000 %
    \ensuremath{%
      % \displaystyle % larger fractions, ...
      \IfNoValueF{#1}{\label{#1}}% add label if optional argument is used
      #2%
    }%
    \hfill\@eqnnum
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
  \hline
  \textbf{solved for $x$} & \textbf{solved for $y$}\\
  \hline
  \InlineEquation[eq:first]{x = a + b} & \InlineEquation[eq:second]{y =d + e}\\
  \InlineEquation[eq:third]{x = d + b \times k} & \InlineEquation{y = j^{2}} \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}

See \eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{eq:second}, \eqref{eq:third} and the one without
label.
\end{document}
```

[image: table with inline math numbered]

BTW: I would recommend to not use vertical lines and lots of horizontal lines. See package [`booktabs`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/booktabs) for information about how to make nice tables.

If the equation number should also depend on the table number, you could use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{caption}% To have captions formatting to be used above table instead of below.
\newcounter{outsideequation}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TableEquation}{om}{%
  \begingroup
    % Put \refstepcounter at the beginning, because
    % package `hyperref' sets the anchor here.
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    % prevent line breaks inside equation
    \relpenalty=10000 %
    \binoppenalty=10000 %
    \ensuremath{%
      % \displaystyle % larger fractions, ...
      \IfNoValueF{#1}{\label{#1}}% add label if optional argument is used
      #2%
    }%
    \hfill\@eqnnum
    \endgroup
}
\newenvironment{UseTableEquations}{%
  \setcounter{outsideequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \counterwithin{equation}{table}%
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{outsideequation}}%
  \counterwithout{equation}{table}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \caption{Table with equations}
  \begin{UseTableEquations}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
      \toprule
      \textbf{solved for $x$} & \textbf{solved for $y$}\\
      \midrule
      \TableEquation[eq:first]{x = a + b} & \TableEquation[eq:second]{y =d +
        e}\\
      \addlinespace
      \TableEquation[eq:third]{x = d + b \times k} & \TableEquation{y = j^{2}} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{UseTableEquations}
\end{table}

See \eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{eq:second}, \eqref{eq:third} and the one without
label.

\end{document}
```

[image: equation number depending on table number]

or with table caption below the table:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcounter{outsideequation}
\makeatletter
\NewDocumentCommand{\TableEquation}{om}{%
  \begingroup
    \advance\c@table by 1\relax% because table counter is 1 to low
    % before \caption
    % Put \refstepcounter at the beginning, because
    % package `hyperref' sets the anchor here.
    \refstepcounter{equation}%
    % prevent line breaks inside equation
    \relpenalty=10000 %
    \binoppenalty=10000 %
    \ensuremath{%
      % \displaystyle % larger fractions, ...
      \IfNoValueF{#1}{\label{#1}}% add label if optional argument is used
      #2%
    }%
    \hfill\@eqnnum
    \endgroup
}
\newenvironment{UseTableEquations}{%
  \setcounter{outsideequation}{\value{equation}}%
  \setcounter{equation}{0}%
  \counterwithin{equation}{table}%
}{%
  \setcounter{equation}{\value{outsideequation}}%
  \counterwithout{equation}{table}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{1.2}
  \begin{UseTableEquations}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
      \toprule
      \textbf{solved for $x$} & \textbf{solved for $y$}\\
      \midrule
      \TableEquation[eq:first]{x = a + b} & \TableEquation[eq:second]{y =d +
        e}\\
      \addlinespace
      \TableEquation[eq:third]{x = d + b \times k} & \TableEquation{y = j^{2}} \\
      \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{UseTableEquations}
  \caption{Table with equations}
\end{table}

See \eqref{eq:first}, \eqref{eq:second}, \eqref{eq:third} and the one without
label.

\end{document}
```

[image: caption below table]