Spacing when using \frac command
I have a litte problem with using the \frac command, because the text that is written before it, it will be spaced. How can i fix this? It is on purpuse that there is two lines of text one under the other. It can work if i dont have the \displaystyle in my equation (the second equation) but then it just looks small.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = newest}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{delarray}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage[paperheight=11.693in,paperwidth=8.267in]{geometry}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{Times New Roman}

\geometry{left=3.4cm}
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

    \text{\textit{x} og \textit{y} er ligefrem proportionale} \hspace{1cm} \text{(8)} \hspace{0.5cm} $\textit{y}= \textit{k}\cdot\textit{x}$ \hspace{2cm} $\displaystyle \frac{\textit{y}}{\textit{x}}= \textit{k}$\\ 

\text{Proportionalitetsfaktor \textit{k}}

\end{document}


welcome! could you make your snippet into a complete example we can compile?

im totally new to this. What do you mean @cfr

@olivers82 you just include a code that we can copy and paste to run in LaTeX. It would be something like \documentclass{article} \usepackage{mathtools} \begin{document} [your code here] \end{document}.

I don't quite understand the problem? Also, why not use \begin{equation} \end{equation} or \begin{align} \end{align} to get numbered equations?

The problem is that when i use the \frac command, the spacing between the the text lines that are over and under eachother will be further apart. I dont know how else to explain it. But with the \begin{equation} command then the whole equation will me moved to the middle of the page. I want the text and the equation to be exactly on the same lign with eacother so therefor im using $ $ instead. Does it make sense?

for example try to remove the \displaystyle command and try to run it. See how the spacing between the two text lines that are under and over eachother is closer rather than if you use the \displaystyle then they will be further apart. (so the lower text line will be moved more down). I use the \displaystyle so the equation with \frac gets to normal size

You could just use \vspace*{-0.5\lineskip} or something between the lines I'd imagine.

Ohh i also dont use \begin{equation} for the numbered equations because i want it to appear before the equation and not after

Also, try to keep the example minimal, meaning: don't include packages that isn't needed to reproduce your specific problem. In this case, most packages are redundant to replicate the error.

Times New Roman is a text font, not a math font. You're barely using math mode -- what's with all the \textit commands? Never use the inputenc package when using LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile the document. Last but definitely not least, what might "because the text that is written before it, it will be spaced" mean? Please clarify.

I use all the packages for all the other 19 pages i have in that document. I just cant seem to get this to work. I just tried with \vspace*{-0.5\lineskip}. I did not work. Do you have any other suggestions?

it makes no sense to load mathptmx with unicode-math. mathptmx provides a traditional (7-bit) maths set up. it directly conflicts with unicode-math.

first, you cannot use all those packages because some are simply incompatible so only one of them can 'win'. second, it doesn't matter what is needed for the other 19 pages. all that matters is what is needed to reproduce the problem. we're not saying: delete all those packages in your real document. we're saying: delete the ones we don't need to reproduce from your minimal example.

I use the \textit command and \text to all the letters and numbers in my equations because i really like how they look with the Times New Roman font. What i meant about "because the text that is written before it, it will be spaced" i meant that there will be more space between the upper text and lower text when using \displaystyle to make the letters in the \frac command to normal size

Please do yourself a huge favor and replace \usepackage[paperheight=11.693in,paperwidth=8.267in]{geometry} with \usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}.

There are several excellent reasons for why text fonts are supposed to be used for text material and math fonts are supposed to be used for math material. Please replace \setmathfont{Times New Roman} with \setmathfont{XITS Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase] and familiarize yourself with math mode.

Will the XITS Math look like the Times New Roman font?

@olivers82 - Yes.

@olivers82 - you wrote, "Ohh i also dont use \begin{equation} for the numbered equations because i want it to appear before the equation and not after." If you want equation numbers to be placed on the far left, just specify leqno as one of the \documentclass options.

The entire reason for having separate text and display styles for math is so that the inline text style layout does not disturb the inter-line spacing in paragraphs.  So the correct markup is
abc ... $\frac{y}{x}=k$

not
abc ... $\displaystyle \frac{y}{x}=k$

By using display style in an inline context you are explicitly telling TeX to break the even interline space.
If you need display style, then you should use a displayed equation, so
abc ...
\[\frac{y}{x}=k\]

Note that in either case you should not ever need an explicit \displaystyle command in a document, it is used to define display environments such as align that use displaystyle while internally using inline math in table cells.

Maybe something like this?

\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[danish]{babel}
\usepackage[a4paper,left=3.4cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{unicode-math} % 'unicode-math' loads 'fontspec' and 'amsmath' automatically

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
\setmathfont{XITS Math}[Scale=MatchLowercase] % or some other suitable math font

\begin{document}

$x$ og $y$ er ligefrem proportionale 
\hspace{1.0cm} (8) % what is '(8)' supposed to mean?
\hspace{0.5cm} $y= k\cdot x$ 
\hspace{2.0cm} $\smash{\dfrac{y}{x}}= k$

Proportionalitetsfaktor $k$
\end{document}


OMG! Thank you so Much! That looks just like i wanted it. Btw the (8) is the number of that equation

@olivers82 never hard-code labels of equations or anything else. it breaks cross-referencing and, if used, it will break hyperlinks, lists of things etc. it is also a complete pain to maintain as an author. if you insert an equation near the beginning, you have to renumber everything after.

So one last thing and i wont bother anymore. Fx this number (8). if i wanted it just like you just did there. That exact location before an equation. is there a way so everytime i make a new equation they will be numbered automaticly and they all have to be the same distance to the equation (like you did there)?

@olivers82 it gets automatically numbered if you use the equation or align environments. That's why I recommend using them. If you want to make a number for some equation outside I imagine it is more involved.

Thanks for your help.

@olivers82 see this question for in line numbering of equations: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78579/labelled-in-line-equation

@olivers82 - I suggest you change \documentclass[11pt]{article} to \documentclass[11pt,leqno,fleqn]{article}. That way, (a) displayed equations' number will be typeset at the far left and (b) the equations themselves will be placed on the left rather than in the center. And, for goodness' sake, do make an effort to inform yourself about TeX's two math modes: inline math and display math.

So, one thing you can do is measure the difference between the height of $\frac{a}{b}$ and $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$ in a variable, call it \fracHeightDiff. You can then use \vspace{-\fracHeightDiff} to move the text up by the difference. Thus, it will be as if you didn't use displaymode.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{calc}

% Measure height of displayed fraction
\newlength{\fracDisplay}
\settoheight{\fracDisplay}{$\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$}

% Measure height of inline fraction
\newlength{\fracInline}
\settoheight{\fracInline}{$\frac{a}{b}$}

% Find the difference
\newlength{\fracHeightDiff}
\setlength{\fracHeightDiff}{\fracDisplay-\fracInline}

\begin{document}

\noindent $x$ og $y$ er ligefrem proportionale \hspace{1cm} $(8)$ \hspace{0.5cm} $y=k\cdot x$ \hspace{2cm} $\displaystyle \frac{y}{x}=k$ 
\vspace{-1\fracHeightDiff} % Using this to get negative vertical spacing
\newline
Proportionalitetsfaktor $k$.

\vspace{2cm}
\noindent Proportionalitetsfaktor $\displaystyle \frac{a}{b}$ 
\vspace{-1\fracHeightDiff} \newline
Proportionalitetsfaktor $\ \frac{a}{b}$ \\
Propo \\
Propo
\end{document}

However: a word of caution: the fraction will then overlap with the next line. The reason for this spacing is simply so that the text do not overlap. If you restore the original spacing, you run the risk of overlapping text. As shown in the example with a shorter line of text:

